# Python: Can't install pyparsing for matplotlib on Mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pyparsing

I am trying to install **`Matplotlib`** for Python on Mac. First it threw an error stating that **`dateutil`** is not installed. After I installed that, I got the error message that **`pyparsing`** should be installed first. So I started to download **`pyparsing`** and tried to install it, as per the instructions at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Download+and+Installation. However, I am getting the following error message:

[image]

Any help regarding this? Plus, what else do I need to install Matplotlib? I have been trying for hours, first I was getting an error message like `gcc is required` when I was trying to download through `pip`. Then I left that and installed it through the `pkg` file. It succeeded, but when I try to `import matplotlib` I get these messages like `dateutil required`, then `pyparsing required`..

Update:

Following the answer below, I installed a lower version of **`pyparsing`** compatible with Python 2.7, and now `import matplotlib` works. However, still when I am trying to get a dispersion plot from `NLTK`, I am getting a `matplotlib missing` error:

[image]

Specifically, although `import matplotlib` works fine and throws no error, when I try something like `import matplotlib.pyplot as pl` I get this error:

[image]

Comment: 1.3.0 is the one I tried..

Comment: There were a couple of external dependencies that got taken out of the matplotlib source tree (dateutil and pyparseiny among them).

Comment: This should be fixed in pyparsing 2.0.1, to be released in the next day or so.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is a Python 3 language feature (nonlocal), and you must be using Python 2 to run the setup script.  You'll need a version of PyParsing that is 2.x compatible to install instead (assuming you're trying to use Python 2.x).

If you want to build / install python packages that have C-extensions, you should install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), and then the command line tools (used to be a separate download, now it is available in-program from a preference pane).  Then you'll have a compiler installed, which is needed to build any python packages that require c-extensions to be compiled.

You can then use pip to install your package and its dependencies automatically, and build the required c-extensions.

Alternatively, you could install the [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/downloads/), which comes with matplotlib, numpy, scipy, and other scientific computing packages pre-built.  This would be a different python interpreter / install area on your computer, which you would need to use instead of the version Apple ships with OS X.

Comment: Thanks dude. That kind of helped, though my problem is not yet fully solved. Please see the update in question..

Comment: And as for the Enthought link you shared, I downloaded `Canopy`. It comes pre-installed with `Numpy` and `Scipy` all right, but neither `NLTK` nor `mathplotlib`..

Comment: That's odd.  The explicitly list matplotlib in their product description here: https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/free/